# Run repair function of an EXE from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-installer, wix

Is there a way to run the repair functionality of an EXE created using WiX?

Specifically, [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/63298930fb531ba2bb4f23bc3b915dbf1e17e9e1/Tools/msi) program using WiX and defines some commands such as `/quiet`, `/passive`, `/uninstall`, but nothing for `/repair`, but it does offer a button when the installer is run again and the application exists.

Been searching through the source code but I'm unfamiliar with WiX and not sure how the button links back to a particular function, or if there is another built-in Windows action I can use on the compressed MSI.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Ramhound Ah the old StackOverflow "well, what have you done?". Apart from letting you know I've already tried `/repair` and looked through source code without success, what would you like to know? Extracting in 7zip revealed nothing, running `/uninstall /log log.txt` gave a lot of information regarding the ProductCode for the registry so I could try with `msiexec /f` but I have no way to verify that the GUID is unique to the binary I have or is system specific; so access the already included repair functionality would be ideal.

Comment: @Ramhound `./repair` wouldn't be a command, and why would you log to an `.exe`?

Comment: So.. coming out of nowhere.. I have written countless MSI installers.  Wix exe should be nothing more than a wrapper around MSI.  Wix produces MSI installers.  Figure out what .msi was dropped on your system by the exe.  repair that..  I hope I am not just being stupid (I doubt it but possible)